# Cluster tiny tasks in large DAG to large tasks in tiny DAG

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, parallel-processing, graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a task DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph) of 3000+ vertices (i.e.: tasks). For parallelisation, I want to group/cluster tiny tasks into a couple of large tasks, such that any clustered task is suitable for running as a job on a thread. This DAG is executed millions of times, so finding an efficient schedule for multicore processing would be very desirable.

**(Optional) Context:** As a first and simple step, I search for disconnected components in the DAG and launch components on threads. However, I have one very large connected component of 900 vertices, whereas most other components are only 1 to 20 vertices. This 900-vertex-component is still taking most of the time: one processor core takes care of this component, while my other cores deal with the remaining 2100 nodes in parallel. The 2100 other tasks are completed before the 900 tasks, hence this large DAG is the bottleneck.

**Question:** I'm thus looking for an algorithm to cluster these tiny tasks of a DAG into larger tasks, while preserving the semantics. Am I missing some terminology to search for this?

**Simple example:** Consider this task-DAG:

```
    .--> B --> C --> D -.
   /                     \
  /                      |
 /                       v
A --> E --> F --> G ---> H --> I --> J
```

which can be reduced to:

```
    .--> (BCD) -.
   /             \
  /               |
 /                v
A ----> (EFG) --> H --> (IJ)
```

which can be reduced to:

```
    .--> (BCD) -.
   /             \
  /               |
 /                v
A ----> (EFG) --> (HIJ)
```

which can be reduced even further to:

```
(ABCDEFGHIJ)
```

Note that:

- the last situation is the clustering of tasks on a single-thread.
- first DAG has too many tiny tasks and will have a lot of thread-synchronisation overhead.
- the second DAG is a fine reduction, as it can schedule two things in parallel. However, it still has the disadvantage that H and IJ are two separate tasks, where they can be merged to avoid synchronisation overhead.
- the third DAG is a good reduction, as it can schedule two things in parallel.

**More complex example:** Somewhat more realistic in my scenario is is following DAG structure. Consider 100 tasks A<sub>i</sub> and B<sub>i</sub>, where B<sub>i</sub> is dependent on A<sub>i</sub>, where these 100 instantiations are independent of each other. Now one tasks C combines the results of these 100 B<sub>i</sub> tasks.

```
A_0 --> B_0 \
             \
A_1 --> B_1 -+
             |
A_2 --> B_2 -+--> C
             |
A_3 --> B_3 -+
             |
    ...
             |
A_99 -> B_99 /
```

The first reduction would cluster the A<sub>i</sub> and B<sub>i</sub> together into an (AB)<sub>i</sub>.

```
AB_0 \
      \
AB_1 -+
      |
AB_2 -+--> C
      |
AB_3 -+
      |
 ...
      |
AB_99 /
```

However, we still have 100 parallel paths in the DAG. Since I have only n (eg: 4) processors, I would like to cluster these 100 parallel paths into n jobs (eg: of 25 paths), such that I save on the synchronisation overhead of the 100 paths, and only have n paths to synchronise.

```
AB_[00..24] \
             \
AB_[25..49] -+
             |
AB_[50..74] -+--> C
             /
AB_[75..99] /
```

So in this example, we started from 201 tasks, and merged them into 5 tasks suitable to run on 4 threads. This kind of intelligent merging of tasks is what I'm after.

Comment: Your second graph for the simple example is likely wrong (at the moment). As I understand it (EFG) should be in parallel with (BCD) and joined at H.

Comment: @HansOlsson: Yep! Corrected it. Nice catch ;)